# How to make the loop to report progress forward and not back?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In this case the progressBar i'm reporting to start from 100% to 0%
But i want it to report the progress so it will start from 0% to 100%.

```
private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int counter = 0;
    MimekitallLoadedMessages = new List<MimeKit.MimeMessage>();
    MimeKit.MimeMessage loadedMessage = null;
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(emailsDirectory);
    FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();//new FileInfo(@"e:\testmail\" + emailNumber + ".eml");
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        string uid = seenUids[0];
        loadedMessage = MimeKit.MimeMessage.Load(files[i].FullName);
        MimekitallLoadedMessages.Add(loadedMessage);
        downloaded.Add(seenUids[i]);
        counter += 1;
        nProgress = (files.Length - i + 1) * 100 / files.Length;
        backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(nProgress, files.Length.ToString() + "/" + i);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Read this line of "your" code: `nProgress = (files.Length - i + 1) * 100 / files.Length;` and try to figure out what it's doing. That is the line you need to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have a `counter` variable, so no extra counting is needed.
- Your fraction would be `counter` of `Length`
- To convert a fraction/decimal to a percentage, the result is multipled by 100.

Put it all together and you get:

```
nProgress = (counter / files.Length) * 100;
```